# OpenGL on mac gives me an error when calling glGenVertexArrays

Tags: opengl

I have been developing a c++, openg, glfw3 and GLEW project on ubuntu and everything has worked so far. Recently I moved to a mac computer (chip M1 if it's important) and things stopped working.

I have an error on runtime when trying to call `glGenVertexArrays`. The error code is 1282 (0x0502) which according to khronos' wiki means:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION, 0x0502
> Given when the set of state for a command is not legal for the parameters given to that command. It is also given for commands where combinations of parameters define what the legal parameters are.

I printed the OpenGL version with `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and results in:

> Version 2.1 Metal - 71.0.7

Then I tried running `glewGetExtension("GL_ARB_vertex_array_object")` which returns FALSE. I am not sure, to be honest, what exactly this means but I add it in case it's useful.

Is there any way of forcing my mac to run OpenGL in a compatible way with my source code? I thought about stop using **vao**s but I am also depending on a library that is supposedly only tested in windows and linux which maybe uses vaos as well. Also, I guess that I probably have problems with other things which don't yet get the chance to run since the program halts on this error.

To add up, my intention is to have a runnable program in linux and I don't intend on developing for mac. So running a VM with linux should solve the problem. Anyway, if there is a way to also make it work in my macos environment it would be much better.

Comment: Is OpenGL still a thing on M1 MacOS? Why does the version string cite "Metal"? Lastly, why is it GL 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL version `2.1` does not support vertex arrays (vaos), you need OpenGL version `3.0+`. Try invoking a core profile and see if that helps. If not then your version might be maxed out at version `2.1` as Apple does not really support OpenGL well (And especially since your graphics card is directly vendored from Apple). Also a handy tip would to consider Apple's built in graphics API, `Metal`, because they have dedicated to supporting this graphics API.